# JQuery collapsible tabs problem?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to JQuery and for some reason when I add another id selector like `id="a"` to my `<div id="tab-1" class="form-content">` my collapsible tabs wont work how can I fix this problem so I can have multiple id selectors and my collapsible tabs will work also?

Here is the JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".form-content").hide(); //Hide all content
    var firstMenu = $("#menu ul li:first");
    firstMenu.show();
    firstMenu.find("a").addClass("selected-link"); //Activate first tab
    $(".form-content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("#menu ul li").click(function() {

        $("#menu ul li a").removeClass("selected-link"); //Remove any "selected-link" class
        $(this).find("a").addClass("selected-link"); //Add "selected-link" class to selected tab
        $(".form-content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the selected-link tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the selected-link ID content
        return false;
    });

});
```

Here is the HTML.

```
    <div id="body-content">

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1" title="">tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2" title="">tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-3" title="">tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-4" title="">tab 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-5" title="">tab 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="container">

            <div id="a" id="tab-1" class="form-content">
                <p>tab 1</p>
            </div>

            <div id="b" id="tab-2" class="form-content">
                <p>tab 2</p>
            </div>

            <div  id="c" id="tab-3" class="form-content">
                <p>tab 3</p>
            </div>

            <div id="d" id="tab-4" class="form-content">
                <p>tab 4</p>
            </div>

            <div id="e" id="tab-5" class="form-content">
                <p>tab 5</p>
            </div>      

        </div>

    <div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't give a single element 2 different "id" values. It's hard to know what it is that you're trying to achieve.

To give an element more than one "class" value, separate the values by spaces:

```
<div id='x' class='something something-else and-another-class whatever'>
```

Comment: even when i try to give an element 2 different `class` values it wont work either.

Comment: one selector is for css and the other is for the tabs to work correctly

Comment: ?? I would like to help, but that just does not make any sense. What doesn't work when you give the elements more than one "class" value? How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 id attributes. You cannot have 2 id attributes in a tag. As you have a and b as the first id I think it is finding those first over you tab definitions.

If you need a and b I would suggest putting them as a class attribute and select it using $(".a")